# pnpm create vite - react / typescript - blank in browser - error is Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (at main.tsx:6:51)

Tags: reactjs, vite

I seem to be having a few problems today with Vite.

Even creating a new vite typescript app and just running it via

pnpm run dev

In the browser is a blank window and the following error

**Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (at main.tsx:6:51)**

[image]

I think something has broken vite.

Comment: It looks like the typescript is not being compiled down to javascript. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem

I have a c:\projects..\folder which is actually a symbolic directory link to d:\projects..\folder

If I run **npm run dev** the following from the c:\projects..\folder I get my weird error

But if I use the real location d:\projects..\folder then it runs fine.